# How to make InnerHTML of 2 elements switch every time the program is run

Tags: javascript, variables, innerhtml

My task is to make this so that when i press run, the 2 pieces of text switch, so "headline" text appears in the "news", and vice versa.

```
var headline = document.getElementById("headline");
var headline2 = "Student Wins Lottery";
headline.innerHTML = headline2;

var news = document.getElementById("news");
var news2 = "A student has won a million pounds";
news.innerHTML = news2;
```

I'm just stack at how you make them switch around, any help and explanations would be great, cheers.

Comment: You have to separate js and html code

Answer (score 0):

Possible approach:

```js
var headline = document.getElementById("headline"),
    headline2 = document.getElementById("news"),
    str1 = "Student Wins Lottery",
    str2 = "A student has won a million pounds",
    bool = true;

function change() {
  if (!bool) {
    headline.innerHTML = str1;
    news.innerHTML = str2;
    bool = true;
  } else {
    headline.innerHTML = str2;
    news.innerHTML = str1;
    bool = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="headline">Student Wins Lottery</h1>
<div id="news">A student has won a million pounds</div>
<button onclick="change()">change heading</button>
```